# flash as3 Why is there a memory gain when changing alpha value of an object?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, memory

for a periodic table tool I'm making, I've incorporated an effect that changes the alpha value whenever I hover over an element (pretty standard).

I've noticed a mysterious gain in memory when hovering over my elements; using SYSTEM.TOTAL_MEMORY - there would be about 0.005MB increase in memory usage when I hover over an element, which isn't relinquished when I move my mouse off. However, if I move my mouse back on again, there isn't a second memory gain.

By commenting out bits of the function, I've noticed that it's the alpha change that is causing this - here is the code for it:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,highlightthis);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,dehighlight);

function highlightthis(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (evt.target is Element)
        evt.target.alpha = 0.5;

}

function dehighlight(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (evt.target is Element)
        evt.target.alpha = 1;
}
```

Does anyone know why this memory gain is happening when the alpha value is changed? And curiously why it only happens once?

Some extra info: my Element class is a MovieClip, with a couple of TextFields, primitive variables and a MovieClip in it. It has had its mouseChildren property set to false (and buttonMode property set to true).

Comment: I don't think it strange that applying alpha compositing requires more memory.

Comment: Just an update if anyone's interested... I played around with the my Element object (the thing whose alpha value is changing) and tried taking out a few of the TextFields etc. There isn't any memory gain when it is just a MovieClip; it turns out that is it those TextFields that's causing the memory gain - changing the alpha value on those things require more memory!

Comment: I had a look at the adobe documentation for TextField and it turns out that there isn't a .alpha property for it. I did a search on the web as well and apparently to change their alpha value, you need to use the blendMode property, referencing blendMode.LAYER which I assume requires more memory. This must be what Flash is doing in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a shot in the dark, I don't know the reason, but could try to guess. Transparency requires knowing the color of the background, besides, in order to display transparency, you'd need one more byte of information (in BitmapData) per pixel (i.e. 33% increase RGB -> ARGB). So, once the player knows the solid color it doesn't bother to save the invisible background, once the background becomes visible it, naturally, needs more memory to save the color info. Once that happens it either caches that info, or you simply didn't wait until GC cycle.

Comment: I'm guessing its because a ColorTransform  instance must be created behind the scenes.

Comment: something like this - alpha requires blending, which requires more resources. The memory isn't relinquished when you mouse out as the gc only runs when you request memory, and then only if it needs to.

Comment: I have waited for the GC and the memory doesn't get relinquished, so I guess this makes sense... changing the alpha value is, loosely speaking, permanently casting the object into something that needs more memory. I guess it's not a big deal because it isn't a memory leak - I was just curious as to the explanation behind it. I'll play around with it a bit more; I'll make the element class a bit simpler, or simply try doing it with a MovieClip and see if I get the same results, and post here.